# How to save the obtained value after several operations using reactive approach

Tags: java, rx-java, reactor

I want to know the best way to use correct reactive approach handling Mono or Flux.

I want to get initial value from Mono after several operations.
For example:

```
public Mono<SomeObject> test(Mono<Object> object) {
        return object
                .map(this::buildRequestFromObject)
                .flatMap(this::sendRequest)
                .flatMap(this::anotherUsefulWorkWithReturnImpotant)          (1)
                .then(object) <-- is it okay???                                 
                .onErrorResume(this::handleExceptionAndDoSomeWork)           (2)
                .doOnSuccess(object-> saveThisObject(object))                (3)
                .then();
    }
```

1. I need to transform value and do some work and get not Empty Result, else Exception
2. After I need to handle exception if (1) throw soemthing
3. If (1) finished without exception I should save original Object.

Is it the best way to do it? Or maybe i should use subcribeContext for example?

Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: No, this is not the best way as you subscribe twice to the input `Mono` this way which is probably not intended. The best would be to change your program flow so that this method accepts the contained `Object` instead of `Mono<Object>`.

Comment: I got it, thanks! But what if I need to save object from `this::buildRequestFromObject` to use it in `doOnSuccess` (3) for example. How does it usually happen?

Comment: When I need to keep an object across multiple pipeline steps I usually extract that part of the flow into a private method which would have that object as as input and then I call the private method from a flatMap in the main pipeline.